# Odbc Connection Error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, odbc

I am using an ODBC connection from a 64 bit Windows 2012 server to an Oracle database located at another 64 bit Windows 2012 server.

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: Library 'ODBC' 'dbconnection' is not a valid physical location.
ERROR: SQL error return:   ERROR: Library 'ODBC' 'dbconne.
ERROR: SQL error return:   ERROR: Library 'ODBC' 'dbconne.
ERROR: Library 'ODBC' 'dbconnection' is not a valid physical location.
ERROR: SQL error return:   ERROR: Library 'ODBC' 'dbc.
ERROR: SQL error return:   ERROR: Library 'ODBC' 'dbc.
ERROR: Library 'ODBC' 'dbconnection' is not a valid physical location.
ERROR: SQL error return:   ERROR: Library 'ODBC' 'dbc.
ERROR: SQL error return:   ERROR: Library 'ODBC' 'dbc.
ERROR: Library 'ODBC' 'dbconnection' is not a valid physical location.
ERROR: SQL error return:   ERROR: Library 'ODBC' 'dbconne.
ERROR: SQL error return:   ERROR: Library 'ODBC' 'dbconne.
```

with *dbconnection* being the name of the ODBC connection.

Comment: Can you please attach here or upload to pastebin the tnsnames.ora file of both your client and the server?

Comment: Show us code that connects to database. What is your connect string?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed 64 bit Oracle client?

Have you configured TNS using "Net Manager"? There is button to "Test service". Does it work?

Have you configured ODBC System DSN connection using `odbcad32.exe`? There is "Test connection" button.

You question is without code and without connection string. Error you got may be because connect string is not correct.

Examples from `pyodbc` documentation (https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/GettingStarted):

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=testdb;UID=me;PWD=pass')
```

and simpler when DSN is configured:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=test;PWD=password')
```

You will find connection strings specific for Oracle at: http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-in-oraclient11g_home1/

But if you have DSN already configured and tested try to use it:

```
DSN=dbconnection;UI=username;PWD=password
```

Comment: Yes everything is there. The test connection works. The error occurs when i execute an application which uses the odbc to connect to the database.

Comment: It builds connection string from data you provide (user, password, database etc.). What is your connection string? How do you call it? Do you use DSN in your connection string? See my edited answer and read more about connection strings.